# Noun in math mode

Tags: lyx

this is propably an Ubuntu packaging error; but just to confirm...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\noun{name}$
\end{document}
```

... this works on your texlive (2009) distribution with pdflatex?

I get `Undefined control sequence.` on the noun command. Hmm

Comment: Where have you got this from? `\noun` is not a standard LaTeX macro.

Comment: I use TeX Live 2009 in Ubuntu and I also get Undefined control sequence for `\noun`.

Answer (score 7):

This can't work on *any* TeX distribution, since the neither the LaTeX kernel nor the **article** class define a command called `\noun`.

If you used it in the past, it probably was from some package (I don't remember having seen it, though) or defined in the preamble of the document.

In order to write text inside math formulas, load the **amsmath** package and use `\text`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I just found out `\noun` is LyX-specific:

    \newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

So I was really looking for `\textsc` :-)