# Where should I use \textsc?

Tags: fonts, formatting, typography, best-practices, small-caps

When should I use macro `\textsc` ? What is common practice in document like diploma thesis? Should I use it for names of persons, names of described entities of particular interest or in some other cases? Is there a difference in usage between languages?

Comment: What is the definition of `\noun`? Which package provides it? (Maybe) Related: [LyX: Noun](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29784/16595)

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29784/2552: This seems to be a LyX specific thing: It's apparently simply defined as `\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}`, so your question could be rephrased to "What things should I print in small caps?" (which in turn is probably off topic).

Comment: @Jake Doesn't stand `\textsc` for small caps?

Comment: @Jake Thanks. I have changed `\noun` to `textsc`. If that is of topic... Then where should I ask?? No community has better knowledge of correct documents formatting then this one. And if it is of topic then what is that popular formatting tag for?

Comment: The reason @Jake thinks this is off topic is that conventions vary quite considerably from field to field and language to language. In my field, (linguistics) small caps are commonly used to mark syntactic categories in examples (perhaps this is the source of your `\noun` example) but this is a question that can't be answered with any generality and is not really related to TeX but to conventions in your field.

Comment: Following on from @AlanMunn’s comment, I’d simply advise that you look at publications (articles, theses, books) in your area and use small caps (and all other typographic styles) as per the conventions in your field.  Your advisor should be a source of advice about specifics.

Comment: One more comment: as a general rule, you shouldn't ever use such text formatting commands directly, but use them within some sort of more semantic markup.  This is probably the source of the `\noun` macro you referred to earlier.  So if you decide that all elements of the kind "foo" should be set in small caps, you should make a command `\foo` which then uses `\textsc`.

Comment: This topic might be suited for [graphicdesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) under their tag [typography](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography).

Comment: Thank you all for helpful comments. I have upvoted some of them. Still, this question as such is probably going to stay unanswered.

Comment: @drasto Depending on what your field is, there might either be an appropriate Stack Exchange site for it or [academia.se] might be good, too. I'd say, however, that we should close the question here as off-topic.